# Change Directory in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, cd

I have a very basic question (sorry) but I'm having trouble changing directories in my mac terminal.

[image]

I want to return to the agustina.garcia directory, could someone tell me which command I need to use?

Thanks!!

Comment: This question should be asked at [apple.se] or [su] instead, as it is a basic OS operation question and not a programming question.

Comment: After doing `cd ~`, enter `pwd` and tell us what it shows you.